# Wildfly inter-app quickstart

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, wildfly-10

I'm getting a NPE when trying to run the "inter-app" quickstart deployed on a Wildfly 10.0.0.Final AS. The NPE is thrown after accessing the application as described in the readme (https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/10.x/inter-app).

Am I doing something wrong or does the quickstart not work?

Exception I'm getting:

```
10:55:54,598 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /wildfly-inter-app-appA/index.jsf: javax.servlet.ServletException
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:671)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.ee.EEResourceProducerField.create(EEResourceProducerField.java:144)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:70)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:101)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:742)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getInjectableReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:842)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:92)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:378)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:389)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector$1.proceed(ResourceInjector.java:70)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:48)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:121)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:159)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:70)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:101)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:742)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.lookup(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:120)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.getValue(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:90)
    at org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.weld.ForwardingELResolver.getValue(ForwardingELResolver.java:46)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:188)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:116)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getBase(AstValue.java:150)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:199)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:291)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:458)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    ... 27 more
```

Comment: Are you getting deployment errors too?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins No, deployment works fine.

Comment: Double check the logs. There is an issue with that quickstart. The shared module doesn't have the version for the `wildfly-maven-plugin` so if you did `mvn wildfly:deploy` from the root directory it likely won't work.